# PHP var_export - elgg_get_entities

Tags: php, elgg

I am trying to create an API for the social network Elgg. It's working but I am very puzzled by some results. 
This is my API:

```
function my_get_group() {
    $group=elgg_get_entities(array(
        types => 'group',
        guid=>75,
    ));
    return var_export($group[0], true);
}
```

and this is the reult

```
{
status: 0
result: "ElggGroup::__set_state(array( 'url_override' => NULL, 'icon_override' => NULL, 'temp_metadata' => array ( ), 'temp_annotations' => array ( ), 'temp_private_settings' => array ( ), 'volatile' => array ( ), 'tables_split' => 2, 'tables_loaded' => 2, 'attributes' => array ( 'guid' => 75, 'type' => 'group', 'subtype' => 0, 'owner_guid' => 54, 'site_guid' => 1, 'container_guid' => 54, 'access_id' => 2, 'time_created' => 1442385556, 'time_updated' => 1442385557, 'last_action' => 1442455132, 'enabled' => 'yes', 'name' => 'goup1', 'description' => '<p>description1</p>', ), 'valid' => false, ))"}
```

So far so good.
I can now modify my APIto get only the description, by changing

```
//return var_export($group[0], true);
return var_export($group[0]->description, true);
```

which gives me

```
{
status: 0
result: "'<p>description1</p>'"
}
```

Now the part that I don't understand is the following. if I modify my code to:

```
//return var_export($group[0], true);
return var_export($group[0]->briefdescription, true);
```

I get

```
{
status: 0
result: "'brief description1'"
}
```

Can someone explain me where this data comes from? I cannot see any mention of briefdescription when I run 
        return var_export($group[0], true);

Thanks for your help
bonododo

Answer (score 0):

All of those values come through [PHP magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) `__get` and `__set`. The reason you see description in `var_export` result is that it's [an attribute](http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/design/database.html?highlight=entities#elggobject), the `briefdescription` is a metadata.

Have a look at [documentation](http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/design/database.html), especially:

- [Data model overview](http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/design/database.html#datamodel)
- [Metadata section](http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/design/database.html#metadata)
- [ElggGroup-specific attributes](http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/design/database.html#elgggroup)

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I had a look to the documentation prior to my question, and after your answer, and I am still confused as it seems I cannot find my answers. Where do you find in the documentation the list of attributes of ellg_user, and where did you see that briefdescription is a metadata. Thanks again for your help and time, it's really appreciated

Comment: You have the list of attributes that does not include `briefdescription`, everything else is always MetaData. It would work the same if it was called `mycustombriefdescription`. You just need to get used to the EAV model that's very flexible in that matter, only attributes are "special case". Basically you are not guaranteed to get all the fields when running `var_export` especially as it's technically private properties and it involves internal caching of metadata that's not always populated.